# How can I generate equal spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I need to generate cpp code with python.

Let's assume

```
int x;
double y;
```

Note: it can be other types.

How can I generate equal spaces ?

I want to get:

```
int    x;

double y;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you propose to generate C++ code with Python? Have you tried something? Are you not getting equal spaces? Please share current output and expected output.

Comment: Side-note: C++ doesn't care about spacing, and most style guides would reject spacing like this, so why bother?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str` formating:

```
>>> "{:<10}{};".format("int", "x")
'int       x;'
>>> "{:<10}{};".format("double", "y")
'double    y;'
```

Comment: is there option to write with f"" ? @Netwave

Comment: @Alex, just use `f{variable_name:<10}{other_variable};`